# Is there a way to negate a pattern case match inside an if condition?

Tags: dart

With pattern matching, it is easy to create a condition like this:

```
if (json case {"data": final Map data, "changed": final List changed}
        when changed.isNotEmpty) {
  ... perform some work with 'data' and 'changed'.
}
```

However, this leads to the unreadable code (in terms of nesting), if you have multiple patterns to apply.

What I would like to do is have pattern guard clauses, such that I can write something like this:

```
if (NOT json case {"data": final Map data, "changed": final List changed}
        when changed.isNotEmpty) {
  return;    
}
... perform some work with 'data' and 'changed'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types lists the types of patterns supported by Dart, and there is no logical-NOT pattern mentioned.

However, you can still avoid a [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)) by doing:

```dart
if (json case {"data": final Map data, "changed": final List changed}
        when changed.isNotEmpty) {
} else {
  return;
}

// ... perform some work with 'data' and 'changed'.
```